# How to catch empty results of a php mysqli query

Tags: php, mysqli, stop-words

Here is the query:

```
$stmt = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT `title`,`description`,`postid` FROM `posttd` WHERE MATCH `title` AGAINST ( ? IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
$stmt->execute();
```

The value of `$value` is 'test1', 'other' and 'test2'

The value 'other' is a mysql stopword. So when it is passed through the query it results to nothing.

Just want to know how to catch it so that I can take it out of the `$value` array.

`var_dump($stmt->execute());` will give `bool(true)` on all three.

As much as possible I don't want to filter the `$value` for stopwords before running it in the query.

`var_dump($stmt)` after `$stmt->execute();` will result to the following:

**test1 var_dump**

```
object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (9) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }
```

**test2 var_dump**

```
object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (9) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(3) }
```

**other var_dump**

```
object(mysqli_stmt)#6 (9) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(1) ["field_count"]=> int(3) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(2) }
```

The only difference is `object(mysqli_stmt)#6`

Any ideas?

Comment: You can just wrap your parameter with ''?

Comment: Can you explain further? Do you mean 'SELECT `title`,`description`,`postid` FROM `posttd` WHERE MATCH `title` AGAINST ( "?" IN BOOLEAN MODE)'?

Comment: What is mysql stopword?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
   // do what you want here
}
```

The above statement make sure if there is data then only it will go inside the condition.

Comment: rowCount() is pdo right? mysqli version is $stmt->num_rows if I'm correct, brb i'll go and try it first.

Comment: for mysqli try if ($stmt->field_count) { }

Comment: both field_count and num_rows are returning true. I'm still unable to catch empty results. Any other ideas?

Comment: echoing `field_count` results to a value of 3 for all `$value` values even the stopword

Answer (score 0):

You should just use

```
if($res = $stmt->get_result()) {
    //this means query returned some rows
}
else {
    //and this means the result was empty
}
```

---

And, yes, it does require your php to be compiled with mysqlnd (native driver) or else you will get undeclared `mysqli_stmt::get_result()` function error or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

So I am unable to catch it using a built-in function. Instead I made a simple test to catch empty results. Here it is:

```
$bindarray = array('+test1','+other','+test2');
foreach($bindarray as $key=>$value)
{
echo $value; // NOTE1: This echo prints +test1, +other, and +test2
$stmt = $dbconnect->prepare("SELECT `title`,`description`,`postid` FROM `posttd` WHERE MATCH `title` AGAINST ( ? IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $value);
echo 'Bind:'.$value; // NOTE2: This echo prints +test1, +other, and +test2
$stmt->execute();
echo 'Execute:'.$value; // NOTE3: This echo prints +test1, +other, and +test2
$stmt->bind_result($rtitle,$rdescription,$rpostid);
    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo 'Fetch:'.$value; // NOTE4: This echo prints +test1 and +test2 ONLY
        if(!empty($value))
        {
            if(!in_array($value, $goodvalues))
            {
                array_push($goodvalues,$value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So as you can see on **NOTE4** `$value` did not fetch anything (`$stmt->fetch()`) so it did not pass through the while loop, so it did not get included in the `$goodvalues` array, SO I was able to separate the stopwords from the array.

If you are able to catch stopwords using built-in functions pls. share.

Thanks